# operator *: не удается сопоставить определение функции существующему объявлению

Tags: c++

Имеются классы:

```
namespace gmath
{
   template<class T, size_t s>
   class alignas(s) Vector3 : public _Vector<T>
   {
   public:
       template<class T1, size_t s>
       friend Vector3<T1, s> operator*(const Matrix3<T1, 64>& m, const Vector3<T1, s>& v);
       // здесь члены и другие объявления
   }


   template<class T, size_t s>
   class alignas(s) Matrix3 : public _Matrix<T, 3>
   {
        // здесь объявления и члены
   }
}
```

И есть реализация выше объявленного метода:

```
template<class T1, size_t s>
Vector3<T1, s> gmath::operator*(const Matrix3<T1, 64>& m, const Vector3<T1, s>& v)
{
    // здесь код
}
```

Пишу в Visual Studio 2017, при использовании данного оператора студия показывает, что он перегружен и находит его. Но при компиляции получаю это:

Ошибка  C2244   operator *: не удается сопоставить определение функции существующему объявлению

Ошибка указывает именно на этот метод.
MSDN сказал, что при использовании шаблонов следует проверить сопоставление реализации внимательно...Просмотрел, не нашёл. Куда копать?

Comment: Определенно стоит продемонстрировать код вызова. Реализация оказывается в той же единице трансляции, что и объявление?

Comment: @free_ze да, разумеется реализация в едином файле.

Comment: краткий ответ: дружественную шаблонную функцию (operator*) необходимо описать прямо в классе (ее реализацию)

Comment: @acade ниже написал ответ, посмотрите, может укажете почему именно так работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код воспроизведен неаккуратно. Как вам удалось использовать тип `Matrix3` до его объявления? Имя параметра шаблона нельзя переиспользовать в качестве параметра вложенного шаблона. У вас имя `s` переиспользуется таким некорректным образом. Во внутреннем friend-объявлении придется использовать другое имя для шаблонного параметра `s`.

Что касается основной проблемы, то для того, чтобы определить член пространства имен `gmath` за пределами пространства имен `gmath` надо сначала *объявить* этот член пространства имен `gmath` *внутри* этого пространства имен. Того friend-объявления, которое вы сделали внутри класса, недостаточно. Оно лишь *ссылается* на "будущий" член пространства имен `gmath`, но не создает видимого объявления. Поэтому компилятор просто не знает, что за функцию вы пытаетесь определить за пределами пространства имен `gmath`.

Вам в ваше пространство имен надо добавить явное объявление вашего оператора

```
namespace gmath
{
  template<class T, size_t s>
  class alignas(s) Matrix3 : public _Matrix<T, 3>
  {
    // ...
  };

  template<class T, size_t s>
  class alignas(s) Vector3 : public _Vector<T>      
  {
    template<class T1, size_t u>
    friend Vector3<T1, u> operator*(const Matrix3<T1, 64>& m, const Vector3<T1, u>& v);
    // ...
  };

  template<class T, size_t s>
  Vector3<T, s> operator*(const Matrix3<T, 64>& m, const Vector3<T, s>& v);
}
```

Также за пределами пространства имен `gmath` шаблон `Vector3` называется `gmath::Vector3`. Именно так его и надо именовать в типе возвращаемого значения вашей функции при использовании "классического" синтаксиса

```
template<class T, size_t s>
gmath::Vector3<T, s> gmath::operator*(const Matrix3<T, 64>& m, const Vector3<T, s>& v)
{
  // ...
}
```

К объявлениям параметров это замечание не относится.

Возникает вопрос: а с чего это вдруг вы взялись определять ваш оператор за пределами пространства имен? Почему вы просто не определили его внутри и не избежали почти всех этих ненужных сложностей?

Comment: Спасибо за очень подробный ответ. Отвечаю Вам: просто эксперименты. Теперь буду знать подробнее про всё.